# How to reset USB controllers?

Tags: linux, usb

When I plug in my no-name USB 2.0 hub
with a mouse and a keyboard connected to it,
that USB port on my computer stops working:
Devices connected to it,
whether through a hub or directly,
are not detected anymore.

A restart of the system makes the port work again,
but I'd rather have less harsh method,
which only "resets" the USB controllers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote a script that works for me (on Debian 11):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Resets all USB host controllers of the system.
# This is useful in case one stopped working
# due to a faulty device having been connected to it.

base="/sys/bus/pci/drivers"
sleep_secs="1"

# This might find a sub-set of these:
# * 'ohci_hcd' - USB 3.0
# * 'ehci-pci' - USB 2.0
# * 'xhci_hcd' - USB 3.0
echo "Looking for USB standards ..."
for usb_std in "$base/"?hci[-_]?c*
do
    echo "* USB standard '$usb_std' ..."
    for dev_path in "$usb_std/"*:*
    do
        dev="$(basename "$dev_path")"
        echo "  - Resetting device '$dev' ..."
        printf '%s' "$dev" | sudo tee "$usb_std/unbind" > /dev/null
        sleep "$sleep_secs"
        printf '%s' "$dev" | sudo tee "$usb_std/bind" > /dev/null
        echo "    done."
    done
    echo "  done."
done
echo "done."
```

NOTE:

- It requires root access to reset the controllers.

Idea taken from:
https://www.linux.org/threads/resetting-the-usb-subsystem.10404/

Comment: See also the `usbreset` utility in `usbutils` that does a `ioctl(fd, USBDEVFS_RESET, 0)` on `/dev/bus/usb/$bus/$dev`. Don't know how effective it would be in your use case.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas AFAICT, `usbreset` (from `usbutils`) only works with devices, not controllers (root hubs). When I run `usbutils` with no options, I get a list of (attached) devices but no controllers or root hubs. If I run `[sudo] usbreset` against a controller/root hub (`dev` set to `001`), `usbreset` prints `No such device found` and exits.

Comment: This worked for me (Debian trixie) my USB-A 3.x (>0) to USB-C, plugged into an SSD was recognised as   Speed: 480Mb/s (high) initially, then not recognised, then after this reset as Bus:    Speed: 5Gb/s (super)